# Join two tables to get the number of total access for user in MySql

Tags: mysql

In my MySql I have two tables: `tblN1` and `tblN2`.

The table `tblN1` is an old table where are memorized account access in restricted area on the website.

The table `tblN2`is a new table where are memorized account access in restricted area on the website.

If try this query on `tblN1` :

```
mysql> SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS TotalN1
FROM
    `tblN1`
WHERE
    UserN1 IN ('7047505')
AND dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
AND CURDATE();
+---------+
| TotalN1 |
+---------+
|       4 |
+---------+
1 row in set
```

The return of this query is `4`.

If try this query on `tblN2` :

```
mysql> SELECT
    COUNT(*) as TotalN2
FROM
    `tblN2`
WHERE
    UserN2 IN ('7047505')
AND dateN2 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
AND CURDATE();
+---------+
| TotalN2 |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
1 row in set
```

The return of this query is `0`.

I'm trying to join two tables to get the number of total access for user.

```
mysql> SELECT
    (
        COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) + COUNT(DISTINCT CA.ID)
    ) AS SuperTotal,
    COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS TotalN1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CA.ID) AS TotalN2,
    UserN1 AS UserN1,
    UserN2  AS UserN2
FROM
    `tblN1` A
JOIN `tblN2` CA ON A.UserN1 = CA.UserN2
WHERE
    CA.UserN2 IN ('7047505')
AND (
    dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
    AND CURDATE()
    AND `dateN2` BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
    AND CURDATE()
);
+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| SuperTotal | TotalN1 | TotalN2 | UserN1 | UserN2 |
+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
|          0 |       0 |       0 | NULL   | NULL   |
+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+
1 row in set
```

The return is `0` for all fields, why?

Please help me, thank you in advance.

**Edit #1**

```
mysql> SELECT sum(total) as Total FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM `tblN1`
    WHERE UserN1 IN ('7047505')
          AND dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND CURDATE()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `tblN2`
    WHERE UserN2 IN ('7047505')
          AND dateN2 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND CURDATE()
    ) AS t;


+-------+
| Total |
+-------+
| 0     |
+-------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM  tblN1 A JOIN tblN2 CA ON A.UserN1 = CA.UserN2` to check if join is correct

Comment: If Join is correct you need to check `WHERE` clause so now try `SELECT * FROM tblN1 A JOIN tblN2 CA ON A.UserN1 = CA.UserN2 WHERE
    CA.UserN2 IN ('7047505')
AND (
    dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
    AND CURDATE()
    AND dateN2 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
    AND CURDATE()
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join causes the 0s to be returned. From your example it is clear that the given user does not have any records satisfying the where criteria in the 2nd table. When you join the 1st table on the 2nd table on user id, no results are returned from the 2nd table, so the join eliminates the corresponding record from the 1st table.

UPDATE:

Instead of using join just combine the 2 queries with union in a subquery and add them up in the outer query:

```
SELECT sum(total) as Total FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM `tblN1`
    WHERE UserN1 IN ('7047505')
          AND dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND CURDATE()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `tblN2`
    WHERE UserN2 IN ('7047505')
          AND dateN2 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND CURDATE()
    ) AS t
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your query but the return is `0`

Comment: Then there are no records satisfying the where criteria in any of the tables.

Comment: Yes, I have column `dateN1` on `tblN1` and `dateN2` on `tblN2`

Comment: The return of total is `0` please see my **Edit 1** in my first question, thanks.

Comment: In this case both queries within the union return 0. Since I copy - pasted your queries from the question (just reformatted them), you have to check those yourself.